# Find and move hidden files from sub-directories with batch file not working

Tags: windows, batch, file-management, file-transfer

I'm trying to use this batch file to find and move files... but it does not work on hidden files.
What's missing?

```
@echo off
setlocal
set root=E:\backup
set dest=E:\Tmp
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /ad /b /s %root%') do @move "%%f\~$*.SLD*" %dest%
endlocal
```

Comment: for one thing, the /ad switch tells dir to only list directories.

Comment: I don't really understanding the filename part.  What would `~$*.SLD*` resolve to?

Comment: @ENGreen: That looks intended. The `/B` switch lists the results as basic paths, with no additional info. Each result is parsed as the variable %%f in the `for` command

Comment: @paradroid: "~$" [Some or no characters] ".sld" [Some or no characters] I guess?

Comment: joe, is removing the hidden attribute an option?

Comment: joe tech: The hidden files are temp SolidWorks files (like ~$Top.SLDDRW). If I manually unhide the files this works. I was trying to write something that could run as a scheduled task to remove these orphaned files.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to unhide the files anyway, because **move** won't work on a file that it can't find (even if you supply the full filename). There's no flag to give to **move** to get it to look for files tagged with the hidden attribute.

Unhide the files with **attrib -h**. Replace your `for` line with this set :

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /ad /b /s %root%') do (
  @attrib -h "%%f\~$*.SLD*"
  @move "%%f\~$*.SLD*" %dest%
)
```

You could use a more sophisticated tool, like **xcopy** or **robocopy**, that can operate on hidden files. Of course, these are copy tools, so you'll still have to unhide the original files and delete them after the copy finishes.